# Convert excel data into SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a excel which is having some columns (lets say column1, column2, column3, ....so on) and rows, here number of columns and rows are not fixed.

Now data from this excel is copied and inserted into one column (**type - nvarchar(max)**) of some table...now i have to take data from this column and need to show in tabular format in SQL.

If number of columns had been fixed, i can easily convert column value in xml and show data in tabular format. As number of columns are not fixed, please suggest, how to get desired output.

Comment: Not sure wheter I understand your querstion correct ... but geany (http://geany.org) is offering tableconvert as a plugin which is able to transform tab delimited content to a vlaue list usable for insert.

Answer (score 0):

below is my assumption, 
1. you use ',' as delimiter.
2. you not concern about the performance since you insert everything in one column

Will the below helps?

```
/*create table
CREATE TABLE Tbl ( col      nvarchar(max))   

insert into Tbl values ('1,2,3,4'),('1,2,3'),('1,2')
***/

DECLARE @maxcol as int,@i as int
SELECT @maxcol=max(LEN(col) - LEN(REPLACE(col, ',', '')))+1 FROM Tbl
select @i=1 

declare @nvarsql as nvarchar(max)
select @nvarsql =''
while @i<=@maxcol
begin 
    set @nvarsql = @nvarsql + ' ISNULL(DBO.fnString_DelimeterIndex(col,'','',' + cast(@i as varchar) +' ),'''') as COL' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR) + ','   
    set @i = @i +1
end


if @nvarsql <>''
begin
    set @nvarsql = 'SELECT ' + left(@nvarsql,LEN(@nvarsql)-1) + ' FROM Tbl'
end 


PRINT @nvarsql
EXEC (@nvarsql)
```

the Scalar function download from somewhere

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnString_DelimeterIndex]
(
    @Text NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter CHAR,
    @Section SMALLINT
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @NextPos SMALLINT,
        @LastPos SMALLINT,
        @Found SMALLINT,
        @REVERSE BIT

    IF @Section < 0
        SELECT  @Text = REVERSE(@Text)--, @Section=1,@REVERSE=1

    SELECT  @NextPos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Text, 1),
        @LastPos = 0,
        @Found = 1

    WHILE @NextPos > 0 AND ABS(@Section) <> @Found
        SELECT  @LastPos = @NextPos,
            @NextPos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Text, @NextPos + 1),
            @Found = @Found + 1


    RETURN  CASE
            WHEN @Found <> ABS(@Section) OR @Section = 0 THEN NULL
            --WHEN @REVERSE =1 THEN 
            WHEN @Section > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(@Text, @LastPos + 1, CASE WHEN @NextPos = 0 THEN DATALENGTH(@Text) - @LastPos ELSE @NextPos - @LastPos - 1 END)
            ELSE REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Text, @LastPos + 1, CASE WHEN @NextPos = 0 THEN DATALENGTH(@Text) - @LastPos ELSE @NextPos - @LastPos - 1 END))
        END
END
```

results from above sample

```
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
1   2   3   4
1   2   3   
1   2
```